# Android WebView Intent send email with "to" pre-filled

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, webviewclient

below is the html code, when i click this. i want open email and fill the "to" field with "someone@gmail.com"

```
<a href="mailto:someone@gmail.com">Send Mail</a>
```

i'm already try this code, its open the email **but still "to" field is empty**

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
       if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
           startActivity(intent);
           return true;
       } else if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) {
           String mail = url.replace("mailto:", "");
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           intent.setType("message/rfc822");
           intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, mail );
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
}
```

Whats wrong with my code, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it using the [`MailTo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/MailTo.html) class:

```
MailTo mailTo = MailTo.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{mailTo.getTo()});
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mailTo.getBody());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, mailTo.getSubject());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, mailTo.getCc());
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Yes, it implements [RFC 2368](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt) so you can see the supported fields there